# HMAC-SHA512 in mathematica and $SystemShell differences

Tags: import, hashing

Hi I'been trying to rebuild the script to get hmac-sha512 but could not get it work

```
hmac512[key_, message_] :=
Module[
{keyLen = StringLength[key], dkey, opad, ipad, blocksize = 64, 
   method = "SHA512"}, 
  dkey = If[keyLen > blocksize, IntegerString[Hash[key, method], 16], 
    StringJoin[key, 
     Array[FromCharacterCode[0] &, blocksize - StringLength[key]]]];
  {opad, ipad} = 
   FromCharacterCode[
      BitXor[ToCharacterCode@
        StringJoin[
         ConstantArray[FromCharacterCode[FromDigits[#, 16]], 
          blocksize]], ToCharacterCode@dkey]] & /@ {"5c", "36"};
  IntegerString[
   Hash[StringJoin[opad, 
     ExportString[
      IntegerDigits[Hash[StringJoin[ipad, message], method], 256], 
      "Binary"]], method], 16]
];
```

I've tried to overcome the issue and get the relevant result from the shell, but surprisingly, execution of

```
echo -n sometext | openssl dgst -sha512 -hmac qwerty
```

in the shell and scripts in Mathematica 10.0

```
RunProcess[$SystemShell, "StandardOutput", "
 echo -n sometext | openssl dgst -sha512 -hmac qwerty
 exit
  "]
```

and

```
Import["!echo -n sometext |openssl dgst -sha512 -hmac qwerty", "Text"]
```

gives different result from that from the shell

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you do `Import["!/bin/echo -n sometext |openssl dgst -sha512 -hmac qwerty", "Text"]`? From the [echo(1)](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/echo.1.html) man page, "Some shells may provide a builtin echo command which is similar or identical to this utility.  Most
     notably, the builtin echo in sh(1) does not accept the -n option."

Comment: Oh, and for the Mathematica code, change `blocksize` to be 128.

Comment: the Import["!/bin/echo -n sometext |openssl dgst -sha512 -hmac qwerty", "Text"]  worked fine. I knew that i missed something very simple. Thanks a lot!

Comment: But the blocksize to be 128 did not helped

Answer (score 5):

For the Mathematica implementation, setting the blocksize to be 128 (as appropriate for SHA512) gives the following

```
hmac512[key_, message_] := 
  Module[{keyLen = StringLength[key], dkey, opad, ipad, 
    blocksize = 128, method = "SHA512"}, 
   dkey = If[keyLen > blocksize, IntegerString[Hash[key, method], 16],
      StringJoin[key, 
      Array[FromCharacterCode[0] &, blocksize - StringLength[key]]]];
   {opad, ipad} = 
    FromCharacterCode[
       BitXor[ToCharacterCode@
         StringJoin[
          ConstantArray[FromCharacterCode[FromDigits[#, 16]], 
           blocksize]], ToCharacterCode@dkey]] & /@ {"5c", "36"};
   IntegerString[
    Hash[StringJoin[opad, 
      ExportString[
       IntegerDigits[Hash[StringJoin[ipad, message], method], 256], 
       "Binary"]], method], 16]];

hmac512["qwerty", "sometext"]

(* "a7c77de3134ba45ad435e16bfc0fabd411a2ed6d02aacdcbc760c1c49e2ce\
a4f91d8486746d0e750b21d8007c81cb96190c32b732157a6e257d7916ae5ee6fc2" *)
```

which matches with the openssl result

```
Import["!/bin/echo -n sometext | openssl dgst -sha512 -hmac qwerty", "Text"]

(* "a7c77de3134ba45ad435e16bfc0fabd411a2ed6d02aacdcbc760c1c49e2ce\
a4f91d8486746d0e750b21d8007c81cb96190c32b732157a6e257d7916ae5ee6fc2" *)
```

The discrepancy between `Import` and the shell mentioned in the question is due to the shell builtin echo not supporting the `-n` option, i.e.

```
Import["!echo -n sometext | openssl dgst -sha512 -hmac qwerty", "Text"]

(* "5ef0a6c12954a93e5f2fdc897222af57ff243675d357f9dfdf3eb1f93f34f\
a6f54914aca71864f7269c30980899ce7d35e23fceb03fa845cf11adc8d8913b780" *)
```

matches the output of the following shell command

```
echo "-n sometext" | openssl dgst -sha512 -hmac qwerty
```

which also matches

```
hmac512["qwerty", "-n sometext\n"]

(* "5ef0a6c12954a93e5f2fdc897222af57ff243675d357f9dfdf3eb1f93f34\
fa6f54914aca71864f7269c30980899ce7d35e23fceb03fa845cf11adc8d8913b780" *)
```